# git@git:~$ ansible --version ERROR: Ansible requires the locale encoding to be UTF-8; Detected ISO8859-1

Tags: ansible

Installing Ansible on Ubuntu

Ubuntu builds are available in a PPA here.

To configure the PPA on your system and install Ansible run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt install ansible



git@git:~$ ansible
ERROR: Ansible requires the locale encoding to be UTF-8; Detected ISO8859-1.
git@git:~$ ansible --version
ERROR: Ansible requires the locale encoding to be UTF-8; Detected ISO8859-1.
git@git:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
git@git:~$
```

Comment: so check your locale  (command `locale`)and it will not show utf-8. Please do explain why your system is not set to utf-8; that should be the default and not latin-1/iso8859-1

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue in the latest version of ansible. I solved this by doing the following (*my machine was Kali Linux*):

```
sudo echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
sudo echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
sudo echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install locales -y
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

step1- `sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

step2 - update the below line in the file

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en.US.UTF-8"
```

step3

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

finally restart the machine